How to save a file from AdonisJS to MinIO server
I'm using adonisjs v4.1.0, and I'm trying to save a file from my api to the MinIO server
I have this s3 disk on my config/drive.js file
s3: {
      driver: 's3',
      key: Env.get('S3_KEY'),
      secret: Env.get('S3_SECRET'),
      bucket: Env.get('S3_BUCKET'),
      region: Env.get('S3_REGION'),
      endpoint: Env.get('S3_ENDPOINT'), 
      s3ForcePathStyle: true,
      sslEnabled: false,
}

Now, I'm trying to use it like this
const uploadFile = async ({ file, filePath }) => {
  await Drive.disk('s3').put(filePath, file.stream, {
    ContentType: file.headers['content-type'],
  });
}

the file has a value and it came from here
const file = request.file('file', {
      types: ['image'],
      size: '10mb',
})

the problem here is, there's no response from await Drive.disk('s3').put and it seems like the file didn't get uploaded on my MinIO Server.
Here's the whole config of my s3 disk after I log Drive.disk('s3').s3.config, maybe this helps
Config {
    credentials: Credentials {
      expired: false,
      expireTime: null,
      refreshCallbacks: [],
      accessKeyId: 'my-minio-access-key',
      sessionToken: undefined
    },
    credentialProvider: CredentialProviderChain {
      providers: [Array],
      resolveCallbacks: []
    },
    region: 'us-east-1',
    logger: null,
    apiVersions: {},
    apiVersion: null,
    endpoint: 'http://localhost:9000',
    httpOptions: { timeout: 120000 },
    maxRetries: undefined,
    maxRedirects: 10,
    paramValidation: true,
    sslEnabled: false,
    s3ForcePathStyle: true,
    s3BucketEndpoint: false,
    s3DisableBodySigning: true,
    s3UsEast1RegionalEndpoint: 'legacy',
    s3UseArnRegion: undefined,
    computeChecksums: true,
    convertResponseTypes: true,
    correctClockSkew: false,
    customUserAgent: null,
    dynamoDbCrc32: true,
    systemClockOffset: 0,
    signatureVersion: null,
    signatureCache: true,
    retryDelayOptions: {},
    useAccelerateEndpoint: false,
    clientSideMonitoring: false,
    endpointDiscoveryEnabled: undefined,
    endpointCacheSize: 1000,
    hostPrefixEnabled: true,
    stsRegionalEndpoints: 'legacy',
    useFipsEndpoint: false,
    useDualstackEndpoint: false,
    token: null,
    tokenProvider: TokenProviderChain { providers: [Array], resolveCallbacks: [] },
    accessKeyId: 'my-minio-access-key',
    secretAccessKey: 'my-minio-secret-key',
    driver: 's3',
    key: 'my-minio-access-key',
    secret: 'my-minio-secret-key',
    bucket: 'bucket'
  }
}

Please note that I also have the right access key and secret key from MinIO, I also have the right bucket name.
The question here is, what's wrong with this setup since it seems like I can't connect on my MinIO server and the await Drive.disk('s3').put is not responding?
